# How to prevent the Visual C++ linker from including every function whose address is taken?

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker, unused-variables

The question is pretty simple. Let's say I compile & link this code:

```
static char const *foo() { static char const *baz = "0123456789ABCDEF"; return baz; }
static char const *(*bar)() = foo;
int main() { return 0; }
```

The Visual C++ compiler or linker automatically seems to mark the string `baz` as used, and includes it, even though it is clearly never used (despite the fact that `foo`'s address is taken).

Is there any way to make the compiler or linker avoid including code like this that isn't actually used?

Comment: Note that your symbols are static. This means, they are local to the compilation unit, and linker never even sees them, and your question, as stated now, is kinda moot.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it, linker's /OPT:REF option.  You didn't tell us enough.

Comment: @HansPassant: You sure? Look for the string `0123456789ABCDEF` in the executable; is it not there? It certainly doesn't work for me, and I've tried using `cl.exe` versions up to 19.00.24210 (w/ the associated linkers). What flags are you passing? I'm using `cl Temp.cpp /nologo /O2 /link /OPT:REF` (also tried adding `/Entry:main /NoDefaultLib /Subsystem:Console` to remove other crap) and it never works. Not sure what other information I can provide though? What version are you using?

Comment: @hyde: Yes, I'm 100% aware (I commented regarding this on one of the answers below). How does that make the question moot? The string is being embedded *even though* the symbols are `static`. If anything, that makes what the linker is doing even *more* questionable than it otherwise would be, rather than less...

Comment: @hyde: Again, I'm 100% aware. I put `static` here to make the question extra foolproof -- in fact, you can remove it and get the same result with external linkage. Put another way, I just wanted to give the build system more than 1 chance to remove the symbol, and yet it failed on both accounts, so I demonstrated that. It wasn't because I didn't understand what static meant; it was because I understood it just fine.

Comment: @Mehrdad See my comment under the accepted answer, I'm genuinely interested if VC toolchain can actually remove static objects from object files at linking phase (I mean, compiler *could* include information about static symbols in the obj file as such, and linker *could* manipulate them, but that is kinda against how work is generally shared between compiling and linking, so I'll be surprised if it actually does it).

Comment: @hyde: I don't know if you're asking whether duplicating those methods while only referencing one of them from `main` would result in the removal of the other one when they are in the same object file (but separate library), but if you are, then yes -- I believe I tried that and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating foo() and bar() to a different obj file (i.e., a different cpp) is a good start - but not enough.  Turns out that when linking the *executable* the linker pulls in every obj file built with the exe anyway.

The second part of the solution would be to extract the cpp with foo() and bar() into a *static library*, and have the executable with main() link against it.

AFAICT the exact VC linking apparatus isn't officially documented, but surveyed by Raymond [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130107-00/?p=5633).  Also, this will not work if you check '[Use Library dependency inputs](https://ofekshilon.com/2013/04/06/forcing-construction-of-global-objects-in-static-libraries/)'

Comment: +1 Whoa! I just tried it and it works! Seems like merely putting the second `obj` file inside a `lib` file makes it work... but why though? I don't understand, even after looking at the links. How does turning an `obj` file into a `lib` file make it no longer "part of the program" (per the quote on that page)??

Comment: That's just the way it is, with no deeper reason (maybe there used to be one but it's long lost in the mists of time). When linking obj files directly into an executable - all are pulled in, but when you package obj files into a lib and link against it - only the contained obj's that are needed to satisfy linkage are pulled in. This has some surprising and occasionally useful side effects (employed even by mfc and the crt), cf here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130108-00/?p=5623

Comment: BTW, if you're working on large solutions with many static libs chances are you're unknowingly bitten by this behaviour already: https://ofekshilon.com/2014/06/13/vector-deleting-destructor-and-weak-linkage/

Comment: Mindblowing!! I gave my question like a 5% chance of having an answered (expected it to get downvoted actually...) so this is quite a pleasant surprise to me. Thanks!!

Comment: Is this the case of linker actually removing parts of the object files it links with? That is, does the unused static string end up in the executable, if you add unrelated exported symbol in the .obj file with it, and use it from main?

Comment: @hyde No. If you use in main() a symbol from the obj containing the string, this entire obj is pulled in - string included. The linker generally works at obj-file resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The *compiler* has only limited opportunities (if any) to removed unused symbols.  Each source file gets compiled into an obj file with the assumption that everything defined has the potential to be referenced by code compiled elsewhere.  The *linker* gets the duty of optimizing out unused symbols from all the libraries and object files handed to it. And it can be hard, but not impossible, for linkers to ignore only part of an individual .obj input.

This might suffice for you:

1. Move `main` to it's own source file and such that nothing in `main.c` references `foo`.
2. Switch to a Release build.  Make sure `/OPT:REF` is set as your linker optimization option.
3. Do a "build clean", followed by a full build of the entire app.

Comment: Note that the compiler should also be able to figure this out here since those functions `static`. Also note that the linker already *does* ignore parts of the object file when the address isn't taken. It's only when the address is taken that the issue occurs.